# Как исправить ошибку при вызове метода активности из синглтона android?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

Хочу вызывать метод активности при определенных условиях из синглтона. Вот сам метод:

```
fun workingWithBtn(k: Int) {
        when (k) {
            1 -> {
                btn_submit_t.showError();
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    this@LoginScr.runOnUiThread {
                        btn_submit_t.hideLoading()
                        btn_submit_t.isEnabled
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }
            2 -> {
                btn_submit_t.showSuccess()
            }
            3 -> Handler().postDelayed({
                clickCount--
                this@LoginScr.runOnUiThread {
                    btn_submit_t.hideLoading()
                    btn_submit_t.isEnabled
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
```

для того чтобы его вызвать я засетил активность в синглтоне:

```
public void setLoginScr(LoginScr loginScr) {
        this.loginScr = loginScr;
    }
```

и в активности:

```
ms.setLoginScr(LoginScr())
```

при вызове выбивает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

Суть метода в том чтобы он взаимодействовал с элементами экрана. Судя по ошибке у меня не инициализирован нужный мне элемент. Пробовал после инициализации по id попробовать что-то сделать с этой вьюхой, но тоже не получилось. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: лично я, ничего не понял, сверху котлин потом java. Вызов активити происходит командой startActivity(intent), думаю вы про это знаете. Лично мне ничего не понятно.

Comment: я хочу вызвать не активность из интента, а метод активности

Comment: на java все получилось, а вот с котлином почему-то не получается :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему через BroadCastReceiver. Для этого в синглтоне, где нужно (у меня при срабатывании условия) добавляем:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("btn_task"); // тут название вашего фильтра
intent.putExtra("url", 1);
context.sendBroadcast(intent); // здесь context не нужен вообще, но так как это вызов из синглтона то пришлось вставить
```

дальше в активности создаем переменную:

```
lateinit var receiver: BroadcastReceiver
```

присваиваем ей значение:

```
 val filter = IntentFilter("btn_task")
```

и регистрируем "получателя":

```
registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
```

ловим данные:

```
receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                workingWithBtn(intent.extras.getInt("url"))
            }
        }
```

удаляем "получателя" при разрушении активности:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
```

как-то так :)